# Replacing spaces (i.e., " ") or new lines (i.e., carriage return) with underscores - special case

Tags: text-processing

I want to replace spaces (i.e., " ") or new lines (i.e., carriage return) with underscores in a special case - when they occur between two specific strings.

I have html pages and I want to replace the blank spaces and new lines with underscores when they occur between  two specific strings.

Example:

```
lots of text...
page_5.html months ago


This is the password: 6743412 <http://website.com etc...
more text...
```

I want to to go from above to below:

```
lots of text...
page_5.html months ago__This_is_the_password:_6743412_<http://website.com etc...
more text...
```

Basically, I want to do the replacement only between the strings `ago` and `<http`

It is repetitive html so if I can get this to work it would be very helpful and easy to extract the modified text later.

Something using sed or awk would be best for me.

Comment: between strings "ago" and **what**?  btw, newlines aren't carriage-returns (`^M` or `\r`), they are linefeeds (`^J` or `\n`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean 'between "months ago" and "http://"', this`perl` script does what you want:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $join=0;

while(<>) {
    if (m/ ago$/) { $join=1 };
    if (m/http:\/\//) { $join=0 ; s/[[:blank:]]/_/g; };
    if ($join == 1) {
        s/\s/_/g;
        s/_(seconds|minutes|hours|days|weeks|months|years|ago_)/ $1/g;
    };
    print;
}
```

NOTE: I have deliberately used `[[:blank::]]` rather than `\s` in the first `s///` operation above so that it only changes spaces and tabs on that line, not newlines.  With the second substition, I want it to replace all kinds of spaces, including newlines (except for the space immediately preceding `months ago` and the space between `months` and `ago`).

Output:

```
lots of text...
page_5.html months ago___This_is_the_password:_6743412_<http://website.com_etc...
more text...
```

This could also be written as a one-liner, using `perl -p`:

```
perl -p -e 'if (m/ ago/) { $join=1 }; if (m/http:\/\//) { $join=0 ; s/[[:blank:]]/_/g; }; if ($join == 1) {s/\s/_/g}; s/_(seconds|minutes|hours|days|weeks|months|years|ago_)/ $1/' speld.txt
```

Comment: Hi, it actually has to be " ago" as the first string. There is a space before the word ago. Sometimes its months ago, years ago - it varies.

Comment: i've updated the script to work with various time units, not just months.

Answer (score 0):

A Python snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
with open('file.txt') as f:
    f = f.read()
    spl = re.split(r'(\sago\n|<http://)', f)
    des = re.sub(r'\s', '_', spl[2])
    print(spl[0] + spl[1].replace('\n', '') + des + ''.join(spl[3:]), end='')
```

The file is split into parts taking `ago\n` and `<http://` as delimeters using `re.split`. Then the value at index 2 is the desired portion where the replacements need to be done. Finally the file is printed in desired pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{(?<=\bago\b)(.+)(?=<http)}{ ($repl=$1) =~ s/\s/_/g; $repl }sge' file
```

Notes:

- `-0777` slurps the file into a single string
- the "outer" `s///` command finds all the substrings you want to modify
- the "inner" `s///` command replaces all whitespace with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

**use vim, one command from your terminal will do it:**

```
vim -c '%s/ ago\n*/ ago__/g|wq' original.txt
```

original.txt gets modified, so **make sure you back it up first!**